# Why would the same identical SQL queries return a different result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two ActiveRecord queries. One returns 4 which is the right number, and the other returns 11, which is the wrong count. I would have expected both queries to return 4. Even the SQL rendered in Rails console are identical for both AR queries.

First query:

```
campaign.daily_statistics.select('COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count').where(metric: metric).where("properties -> '#{column}' = '#{value}'")[0]['count']
DailyStatistic Load (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count FROM "daily_statistics" WHERE "daily_statistics"."campaign_id" = $1 AND "daily_statistics"."metric" = 'participation' AND (properties -> 'assumed_gender' = 'female')  [["campaign_id", 2]]
=> 4
```

Second query:

```
sql = campaign.daily_statistics.select('COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count')
sql.where(metric: metric).where("properties -> '#{column}' = '#{value}'")
sql[0]['count']
DailyStatistic Load (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count FROM "daily_statistics" WHERE "daily_statistics"."campaign_id" = $1 AND "daily_statistics"."metric" = 'participation' AND (properties -> 'assumed_gender' = 'female')  [["campaign_id", 2]]
=> 11
```

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

In your second query, you're not assigning

```
sql.where(metric: metric).where("properties -> '#{column}' = '#{value}'")
```

to anything. So when you then run

```
sql[0]['count']
```

you're only executing the first part of the query that you assigned to the sql variable.

I'm not sure why the SQL logging output appears as it does. At a guess, it's due to some of the peculiarities of the rails console and when it provides output/inline logging.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be seeing in the rails console is something like:

```ruby
sql = campaign.daily_statistics.select('COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count')
DailyStatistic Load (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count FROM "daily_statistics" WHERE "daily_statistics"."campaign_id" = $1)  [["campaign_id", 2]]
sql.where(metric: metric).where("properties -> '#{column}' = '#{value}'")
DailyStatistic Load (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count FROM "daily_statistics" WHERE "daily_statistics"."campaign_id" = $1 AND "daily_statistics"."metric" = 'participation' AND (properties -> 'assumed_gender' = 'female')  [["campaign_id", 2]]
sql[0]['count']
#=> 11
```

a fix for the 2nd query should be would be:

```ruby
sql = campaign.daily_statistics.select('COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count')
DailyStatistic Load (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count FROM "daily_statistics" WHERE "daily_statistics"."campaign_id" = $1)  [["campaign_id", 2]]
sql2 = sql.where(metric: metric).where("properties -> '#{column}' = '#{value}'")
DailyStatistic Load (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count FROM "daily_statistics" WHERE "daily_statistics"."campaign_id" = $1 AND "daily_statistics"."metric" = 'participation' AND (properties -> 'assumed_gender' = 'female')  [["campaign_id", 2]]
sql2[0]['count']
#=> 4
```